# Dont Save Item in ComboBox

Tags: c#

I have a TextBox, a Button, and a Combobox
When I click the Button, I want the text in Textbox to be added to the Combobox Items

Here is my code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

My form until open. This text shows in the Combobox, but when I close the Form and open it again the text is not longer shown in the Combobox.

I want to save the text to the Collection Items of the Combobox.  I don't want to use a database.

Comment: Where do you want to store them?

Comment: You *have* to use some kind of storage, which could be a database (table), a file on disk, or perhaps even something that stores data in the cloud. This requires effort, and you'll need to decide what effort you are willing to spend. Having said that, excluding databases upfront does not seem a very wise position to me.

Comment: Since it would appear you are just working with some text, you could also *research* a simple text file or user settings.

Comment: You really need to study a bit more because it seems you're assuming that filling a list will automatically be saved somehow. I've got news for you, that's not going to happen in C#. There's a lot more you'll need to get it into a database. Try and brush up on Databases, how to connect and how to Create, Read, Update and Delete (CRUD) data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you need to understand and decide where you wish to store your values.

For the purpose of my example, I have created a simple text file to store these values. The code reads from the file and adds each line as an item into the ComboBox.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Read items from file into a string array
            string[] items = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\ComboBoxValues.txt");

            // Add items to the comobobox when opening the form
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(items);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Add your new value to the combobox
            comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);

            // Put all existing comobo box items into a string array
            string[] items = comboBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

            // Save the array of items to a text file (this will not append, it will re-write the file)
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\ComboBoxValues.txt", items);
        }
```

This may not be the most elegant way of going about it, but from the point of providing you an understanding - this should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like to use File System, you can use Preferences(but it's not recommendable to use preference to memorize large values), check this link to see how [create a new setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

```cs
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string[] strItems = Properties.Settings.Default.items.Split(", ");
         for(int i = 0; i < strItems.length; i++) {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(strItems[i]);
         }
     }

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          //add your new value to the combobox
          comboBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);

          //put all existing combo box items into a string array
          string[] items = comboBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
 
          for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
              //I assumed you had an items key in your settings
              if(i == items.length - 1) {
                  Properties.Settings.Default.items += value;
              } else {
                  Properties.Settings.Default.items += value + ", ";
              }
           }
           //then you should to save your settings
           Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
     }
```